# problem with inserting HTML with insertHTML

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make wysiwyg editor with content editable divs and I'm inserting html with document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, html); but the problem is, when i insert link, and then i want to write after it continues to write INSIDE that link.

EXAMPLE:

how it does now:

```
Hello, <a>stackoverflow.com MyTextAfterLink</a>
```

how it should be:

```
Hello, <a>stackoverflow.com</a> MyTextAfterLink
```

How could i fix this? Thanks.

Comment: consider using jquery, its easy & cross-browser.

Comment: Well, I'm using it, but what its function should i use for this? Are you talking about .html()?

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning to the innerHTML property of a DOM node instead.