# How to use insertHTML or insert html in bootstrap-wysiwyg?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg, inserthtml

This question is probably similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2844567/932965).

I'm using bootstrap-wysiwyg and I want to insert some html to #editor div. Html I want to insert should be intrpreted by browser after inserting to format it. 
For example when I insert:

```
<b>some</b> text
```

I would like to see word some bold and not surrounded with "b" tags.
I guess I should use insertHTML that I found on site: [Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla). Unfortunately I did't find any simple example how to use it.

I ask for simple example like $("#editor").html("**some** text") in jquery.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I tried creating a button like this:

    <a class="btn" data-edit="insertHTML" value="<table><tr><td>Val1</td><td>Val2</td></tr></table>"><i class="icon-table"></i></a>

but didn't work.

Comment: If you wonder, finally I decided to use other wysiwyg.

Comment: may I ask which one? thanks

Comment: I selected https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/bootstrap-live-editor-WB0DFT966 . I also know that my friend choose tinyMCE + https://github.com/gtraxx/tinymce-skin-bootstrap with success.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this using an insertHtml call. So you can tried adding a row like this:

```html
<a class="btn" data-edit="insertHTML <table border='1|0'><tr><td>Val1</td><td>Val2</td></tr></table>" title="Table"><i class="fa fa-table"></i></a>
```